# class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue> as DataContract

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract, svcutil.exe, generic-collections

How to decorate

```
public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

as `DataContract` (or something like this) in `WCF` service?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, if your `ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is **serializable** then since WCF 3.5 SP1 there is no need to mark it as `DataContract` (Please see the question: [WCF datacontract vs class serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722136/)).

Answer (score 0):

You need `CollectionDataContractAttribute`

> The CollectionDataContractAttribute is also intended to be used with dictionary types to handle keyed collections. Dictionary types are classes that implement either the IDictionary or the IDictionary interface, for example, the Dictionary.

Take a look for more details [CollectionDataContractAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute.aspx)